# __copy__ и __deepcopy__

Tags: python, python-3.x

Зачем используется перегрузка `copy` и `deepcopy`, если в стандартных пакетах python реализованы соответствующие функции? Какую роль играют `__copy__`, `__deepcopy__`?

Comment: Если у вас свой объект, то copy и deepcopy тупо скопируют содержимое всех полей. Но если вам нужно, например, не все копировать (при deepcopy), или наоборот - нужно выполнить какие-то дополнительные действия, то нужно переопределить эти специальные методы.

Comment: @insolor Смысл держать и `__copy__` и `__deepcopy__` для переопределения? Кажется, что достатчоно copy

Comment: Не достаточно - по той же причине, почему две отдельные функции для копирования в модуле copy.